# Html and Php image not showing online but showing in localhost

Tags: php, html

The file location of the image is correct and it displays on localhost however doesn't online, how would i be able to get this to work?

I have tried changing the images from png to jpg and using different images and changing the file locations and then updating that on the code however it still does not display the image

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>KMS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
<!--Logo-->
<div id="Logo">

</div>
<!--Logo-->

<!--Menu Buttons-->
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
<!--Menu Buttons-->
</div>


<div id="hContent">

<!--Frames--====================================================================-->

<div id="hFrames">
<!--Information go below-->
<div id="infoCon1">
<img id="kms_img" src="Images/Kmsproductsinformation.jpg" style="width:850px;"/>
<b />
<b />

</div>
<!--Information end-->
</div>




</div>
</div>


<!--
footer
-->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Testing on windows and using a linux server? Note that `Image.jpg` and `image.jpg` are two different file names in linux.

Comment: im testing on xmpp windows and online hosting

Comment: Did you exclude a firewall\script blocking issue?

Comment: I know it's silly, but did you make sure to not only upload your php file, but also your images directory and the images? Make sure you can load the image resources in the browser outside of the html page too (ex: mywebsite.com/Images/Kmsproductsinformation.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img id="kms_img" src="images/kmsproductsinformation.jpg" style="width:850px;"/>` and ensure that your `images` directory and `kmsproductsinformation.jpg` file are in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You've got something funny going on with your DIVS. You have what looks like two additional close DIV tags () towards the end of your file - I'd start by fixing those up.

Having said that it also shouldn't really matter if it's localhost or not, or whether it's jpg or png but PNG would be better if you're setting it to a non-100% width.

Try something basic without all the DIVS or your menu.php file and see if that works.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>KMS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="wrapper">

<img id="kms_img" src="Images/Kmsproductsinformation.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no that doesn't display the image either i cant see the problem because the locations of the files are correct

Comment: I'd suggest you double check that the image you uploaded is actually there and viewable. try open up the image directly in your browser.. http://<host-url>/Images/Kmsproductsinformation.jpg